# How can I differentiate between Providers that provide the same class

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have four providers, that all provide the Instances of Challenge class, to the same Widget.
They are different challenges, but I don't know how to differentiate between the providers, so i wondered, if it's possible to give names to the providers.

Comment: Related: [Flutter - How does MultiProvider work with providers of the same type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56505413/3744182), [how to add multiple ChangeNotifierProvider in same type in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61052629/3744182).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can't, this is the biggest drawback of provider, you can use [riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) instead, it's from the same author, but it has some advantages over a normal provider.

this is what the author of both provider and riverpod sais.

> It makes the provider pattern more flexible, which allows supporting commonly requested features like:
> Being able to have multiple providers of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

No. While you can have multiple providers sharing the same type, a widget will be able to obtain only one of them: the closest ancestor.

Instead, you must explicitly give both providers a different type.

Instead of:

```
Provider<Challenge>(
  create: (_) => 'Something',
  child: Provider<Challenge>(
    create: (_) => 'SomethingElse',
    child: ...,
  ),
),
```

Prefer:

```
MultiProvider(
providers: [
    Provider<ChallengeOne>(create: (_) => Something()),
    Provider<ChallengeTwo>(create: (_) => SomethingElse()),
    Provider<ChallengeThree>(create: (_) => AnotherThing()),
  ],
  child: someWidget,
)
```